# Why are the elements of an array formatted as zeros when they are multiplied by 1/2 or 1/3?

Tags: arrays, io, fortran

I'm writing out the elements of an array as follows:

```
write(6,'(i4,200(1x,e15.7))')Jtot0, (a*PJjv(i,Jtot0,j,iv),i=1,nenerdif,100)
```

where `a` is a constant.  However, when this constant is equal to 1/2 or 1/3 the output is zeros, and if it's equal to 1, every thing goes well.  The array elements are `real*8`.

How can I overcome this, giving that I'm obligated to multiply by a factor of 1/3?

Comment: Do you mean `1/2` and `1/3` (which are zero), or a half and a third?  Please show the assignment for `a`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Fortran `1/2` is an integer division operation which will round down to, in this case, `0`.  Same for `1/3`.  If you want a real result, do a real division operation, such as `1.0/2.0`.  Note that assigning the result of `1/2` to a real variable will set the real variable to `0.0`, that is the integer division will result in `0` and the assignment, which happens next, will cast that value to its nearest real representation.

This business of integer division producing integer results is very common in programming languages.