# integer, do loop, fortran, error

Tags: fortran, fortran90, gfortran

I have the following fortran code defined under. I am trying to change the length of the do loop if i change the value of n. When i try to compile i get the error:
‘a’ argument of ‘floor’ intrinsic at (1) must be REAL. But when i change q and w to be defined as real i get another error message. How can i fix this? q and w is clearly a integer when i use floor(...)

```
subroutine boundrycon(n,bc,u,v)


!input
integer :: n,bc

!output
real(8) :: u(n+2,n+2), v(n+2,n+2)

!lokale
integer :: j,i,w,q

n=30

q=floor(n/2)
w=(floor(n/2)+floor(n/6))


do j=q,w  
u(q,j)=0.0;
v(q+1,j)=-v(q,j);

u(w,j)=0.0;
v(w+1,j)=-v(w,j);

end do

do i=q,w 

v(i,q)=0.0;
u(i,q)=-u(i,q+1);


u(i,w+1)=-u(i,w);
v(i,w)=0;

end do

end subroutine boundrycon
```

Comment: `q` is clearly an integer because it is _declared_ as an integer, not because it is assigned an integer function result.  The argument to `floor` is, in the first one, an integer, and that is the problem.  `q` isn't the argument to the function: `n/2` is.  [`n/2` is integer, for `n` an integer.]  You are, then, asking, how to have `n/2` as a real?

Comment: The result of integer division `n/2` ( for positive `n` )  IS the "floor" of the division, so you most likely just don't need the intrinsic `floor` function  here at all.

Comment: n/2=15, but if i change n to 45 for example, 45/2=22.5 The whole point is when i change n i change the do loop length. I am asking why i get an error when i compile, even though q and w is an integer, and i have fulfilled the requirements for a do loop.

Comment: The error isn't about `q`, it's about `floor(n/2)`.  `n/2` [is an integer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24488741) (and as @agentp says, the flooring is redundant) and one cannot pass an integer to floor.  If you must keep flooring, try `floor(n/2.)` which has a real argument.

Comment: It worked when i only used q=n/2 and w=n/2+n/6. Even when i changed n to 45. It seems that fortran turns a real number 45/2 into a integer on its own. Even though i found that strange. Does anybody know if that is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many people have already pointed this out in the comments to your question, but here it is again as an answer:

In Fortran, if you do a division of two integer values, the result is an integer value.

```
6/3 = 2
```

If the numerator is not evenly divisible by the denominator, then the remainder is dropped:

```
7/3 = 2
```

Let's look at your code:

```
q=floor(n/2)
```

It first evaluates `n/2` which, since both `n` and `2` are integers, is such an integer division. As mentioned before, this result is an integer.

This integer is then passed as argument to `floor`. But `floor` expects a floating point variable (or, as Fortran calls it: `REAL`). Hence the error message:

"[The] argument of `floor` ... must be `REAL`."

So, the easiest way to get what you want is to just remove the `floor` altogether, since the integer division does exactly what you want:

```
q = n/2 ! Integer Division
```

If you need to make a floating point division, that is if you want two integer variables to divide into a real variable, you have to convert at least one of them to floating point **before** the division:

```
print *, 3/2           ! wrong, prints 1
print *, real(3)/2     ! right
print *, 3/2.0         ! right
print *, (3 * 1.0) / 2 ! right
print *, real(3/2)     ! wrong, prints 1.0
```